# Is there a purely singulative-collective language?

Tags: linguistic-typology, linguistic-universals, grammatical-number

I wanted to ask "Is there a language that marks singular?" but found [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singulative_number). So instead, I'm asking: Are there any purely singulative-collective languages?

The (admittedly abstract) idea behind this is that if the answer is affirmative, singulative-collective and singular-plural should be considered different variants of the number category, whereas a negative answer would indicate that they may be different number categories. Note that an affirmative answer would contradict [Greenberg's universal 35](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Greenberg%27s_linguistic_universals#Morphology) (I don't have the book near me, so maybe someone will also expand on this):

> 35. "There is no language in which the plural does not have some nonzero allomorphs, whereas there are languages in which the singular
>       is expressed only by zero. The dual and the trial are almost never
>       expressed only by zero."

Note (entirely besides the point): The last sentence is funny. What does "almost never" mean here --- does he have a counterexample or is he  over-hedging? And what would the dual and the trial being expressed only by zero imply (I suspect it would imply a contradiction, but don't want to dig into this ATM)